# How to watch variable value in method in abstract class

Tags: java, debugging, abstract-class

The IDE is Eclipse, when I debug/Trace and I want to watch the variable in a method in abstract class, but it does not show anything.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Well how will you call a method of abstract class? 
You need to have an instance of the class to call its non-static method.
What I would suggest is, create a class that extends abstract class and call the method in abstract class from extending class as follows.

```
public class AbstractClass {
    public void aMethodToDebug(){
       System.out.println("debug this");
    }
}

public class ExtendingClass extends AbstractClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExtendingClass obj = new ExtendingClass();
        obj.aMethodToDebug();
    }

}
```